# How to detect the language version of Visualstudio?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to detect the language version of VS and do some action depending on it. How to detect it?
Thanks

Comment: There is several language versions of VS - English, Japan etc. I need to detect the language version of current VS. I'm writing the extension so it should not be a problem, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use [DTE.LocaleID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.localeid.aspx), that's what other add-ins use to find their resource DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how to detect default C# language version in Visual Studio 2019:

1. With a mouse, select the required project and right click then in opened window select Properties.
2. In opened Properties Window Select vertical Build tab and click on Advanced button.[image: Build Window]
3. In the opened Advanced Build Settings window it is the row - Language version. In the example: Automatically selected based on framework version.

[image: Advanced window]

4. If the information which framework version corresponds default C# language version, is required the link (Why can't I select a different C# version? - [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)) can be opened. In this page are the rules on how according to the target framework is determined default C# language version and information on how the default C# language version can be changed.
5. Which framework version the project uses are in the project settings file. In the example image [image: Project settings] framework version is .NET Core 3.0 version, so the default C# language version is 8.00.

Comment: The OP was asking about human language (English, Japanese, etc), not the C# language.